# Automatically increment a COUNTIF date criterion

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EUgEwLmiNv9ug66DWzXjnuZ2GzavSbNqs-UTysiwZbM/edit?usp=sharing

I have this Google Sheets with multiple tabs that record projects published on a date.

One of the tabs (`Stats`) records the total number of projects published by everyone on a particular day. I am using COUNTIF in the last tab to record productivity. I don't want the range to change when I drag the formula: I want the criterion to add a date automatically so as to get the result for the next day. I am having to re-write the formula.

`Bob` on the left, `Randy` on the right:

[image: Input]

Output (`Stats`):

[image: Output]

Comment: @pnuts [tag:formula] is for mathematical formulas, not spreadsheet formulas. Instead use [tag:google-sheets-formula]

Answer (score 1):

In Stats!C2 and copied across and down to suit:

```
=countifs(indirect(C$1&"!A:A"),"="&$A2,indirect(C$1&"!C:C"),"Done")
```

should be sufficient, provided you make the column labels in `Stats` match the sheet names (even for spaces).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am grateful for your help. I applied your formula to the sheet as you can see, but it only looks like it is working in one column (D) and not the other (C). Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: omg, it just worked :) Had to read your answer again carefully and remove the spaces in the column names. It was my bad. Thank you so much again.